# stepDown doesn't work when the time hits 12:00 am

Tags: javascript

I have an input form which looks like this:

```html
<input type="time" id="myTime" value="00:00">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Here</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myTime").stepDown(30);
}
</script>
```

Scenario:

I would like to stepDown(30) for 12:00 am. The expected result I should get is 11:30pm, but the value doesn't change. Is there any reason?

Comment: Looks like `stepDown` won't wrap. You can do it yourself though: `const myTime = document.getElementById("myTime"); const value = myTime.valueAsDate; value.setMinutes(value.getMinutes() - STEP_MINUTES); myTime.valueAsDate = value;` (The `Date` methods like `setMinutes` handle out of range values intelligently.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it works! thank you so much, sir!!! i really really appreciate it!

Comment: No worries! Thanks for editing the question. Happy coding! :-)